# Remove / stop 'sw-import.js' from running

Tags: polymer

In recent times I've be developing locally with Polymer, which uses service workers for offline functionality.

Every time, since working with Polymer, I run an application via the console I get error messages relating to `sw-imports.js`. This is especially annoying when working with rails applications as it pollutes the terminal output.

The error message is:

```
Started GET "/sw-import.js?baseURI=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fplatinum-sw%2Fplatinum-sw-register.html&clientsClaim=true&defaultCacheStrategy=networkFirst&importscript=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fplatinum-sw%2Fbootstrap%2Fsw-toolbox-setup.js&importscriptLate=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fplatinum-sw%2Fbootstrap%2Fsw-toolbox-setup.js&precache=&skipWaiting=true&version=1.0" for ::1 at 2015-12-05 16:14:46 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sw-import.js"):
```

The full paste of the console message is [here](http://pastebin.com/5kFs0cEN).

I've accessed `chrome://inspect/#service-workers` in the browser and removed any service workers listed there, but I still get the same console error.

Any idea how to remove the call to `sw-imports.js` completely from my environment?

EDIT: To confirm, this is happening on non Polymer projects where there's no platinum-sw element involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'd have to avoid using service works via `platinum-sw` element. It has a requirement that the file exist: https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-sw#top-level-sw-importjs

Once you have registered a service worker for a particular site, you apparently have to manually de-register it. On Chrome, you do that at chrome://serviceworker-internals/

Comment: I'm not using any Polymer elements in the project. It's a completely independent rails application.

Comment: But the service worker was registered when you did local dev work with Polymer - the platinum-sw is part of the Polymer Starter Kit. Looks like you have to manually de-register it: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2136

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the link. Opening chrome://serviceworker-internals/ and de-registering any running on localhost did the job. If you modify your answer I'll accept :)

Comment: Modified and added the chrome link

Comment: Accepted. Thanks again